# Is it possible to change what is displayed in a Visual Studio Debugger Variables window Value column for a 3rd party class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

When debugging there are various [Variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4dt5w8ta.aspx) windows (autos, locals, watch) containing columns Name,Value,Type.
The value often seems to show an object's class name. In specific cases I would like to show something more meaningful based on the properties of the class instance.

As a specific example, for [CodeTypeReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codetypereference.aspx) I'd like to see a text representation of the type referenced (where valid) based on the [BaseType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codetypereference.basetype.aspx) string or [ArrayElementType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codetypereference.arrayelementtype.aspx) value, rather than seeing "System.CodeDom.CodeTypeReferenceExpression".

Visualizers seem to offer separate dialog windows, rather than a way to populate the value column.

Data tips are per variable rather than per type.

The closest thing seems to be the [DebuggerTypeProxyAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8eyd8zc.aspx) in which case I guess I'm asking "Is it possible to apply an attribute to somebody else's class ?"

I'm mainly dealing with Visual Studio 2010 although a Visual Studio 2008 answer would be useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there are two ways you can accomplish this:

1. By using [OzCode](https://oz-code.com/) (previously BugAid for Visual Studio), a commercial tool that I created, you can simply [star](https://oz-code.com/features/#custom) properties/fields on your type, and have those appear in the Value column on *any* type, whether it is 3rd party or not.
2. You can change your autoexp.cs file, and apply either the [DebuggerDisplayAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerdisplayattribute.aspx) or the DebuggerTypeProxyAttribute to 3rd party types, as described in [my answer on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469001/can-the-debuggerdisplay-attribute-be-applied-to-types-one-doesnt-own/4475679#4475679). For example, this is how you would apply the DebuggerDisplayAttribute to System.Drawing.Pen: `[assembly: DebuggerDisplay(@"\{Color = {color}}", Target = typeof(Pen))]`

This answer applies to both VS2008 and VS2010.

Comment: Thanks - somehow I'd missed autoexp.cs Got this working, but only if I use the DebbugerDisplay parameter Target=typeof(MyAssembly::Foo). Couldn't get TargetTypeName="MyAssembly.Foo" to work including adding brace decoration.

Comment: Fastforward several years and discovered that the `TargetTypeName` works for an instance's `GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName` which is typically an entry in _autoexp.cs_ something like: `[assembly: DebuggerDisplay(@"ProofInPudding {_privateStringData}", TargetTypeName = "MyNamespace.MySubNamespace.MyClassName, MyAssemblyName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")]` which will display `ProofInPooding "foo"` for an instance of that type who's `_privateStringData` field (or property) is set to `"foo"`.

Comment: Or even drop the version/culture/public key token and use `[assembly: DebuggerDisplay(@"ProofInPudding {_privateStringData}", TargetTypeName = "MyNamespace.MySubNamespace.MyClassName, MyAssemblyName")]`

Answer (score 1):

You can override the ToString method for your own classes. The Value is usually just a call to ToString, and if not overridden, this shows the type.

**Update:** For classes you do not have the code for, I cannot provide a valuable answer rather than you *could* wrap the classes ( inherit from ), but that is, hm, strange to be polite ( IMHO ).

Comment: I don't recommend doing this - I used to override `ToString()` to quickly inspect data in objects in the debugger but it has a tendency of becoming permanent code and then it starts introducing all kinds of problems. `ToString()` is intended to provide a string representation of an object while devs usually want to see all kinds of internal detail in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can apply DebuggerTypeProxyAttribute to types you don't own (unless they are private) as explained in my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49674697/1194473)