# DebuggerDisplay for a dictionary's key / value pair?

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to assign a System.Diagnostics.DebuggerDisplay attribute to the definition of a Dictionary?

e.g.

```
Dictionary<int, SomeClass> 
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerDisplay("{Info,nq}")]
public class SomeClass{

    string code {get;set;}

    public string Info { get { return "info" + code; }}
}


// place an attribute here??
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerDisplay("{???,nq}")]
Dictionary<int, SomeClass> dict = new Dictionary<int, SomeClass>();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT**: see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469001/can-the-debuggerdisplay-attribute-be-applied-to-types-one-doesnt-own).

I haven't tried it, but from the documentation, it's possible to apply this attribute at the assembly level. So in theory, you could do something like this:

```
[assembly: DebuggerDisplay("{Key,nq}: {Value,nq}", Target = typeof(KeyValuePair<int, SomeClass>))]
```

I'd be surprised if it lets you get away with specifying a `Target` which is an open generic type, e.g. `Target = typeof(KeyValuePair<,>)` which would work for a KVP of any type. But if you need that, it's worth a try!

Comment: This does not work in Visual Studio 2022.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me!

I wanted to see the key name in addition to the value for Regex groups.

```
[assembly: DebuggerDisplay("Name={Name}, Value={Value}", Target = typeof(Group))]
```

[image]