# "override" ToString or DEbuggerDisplay of an external library's class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tostring, debuggerdisplay

I am developing XNA stuff and using their Matrix structure. When debugging, the value shown for a Matrix is something like:

[image]

which is not super convenient to read. I would like to have something like:

```
{ R:{ 0; 0; 0 } S:{ 1; 1; 1 } T:{ 0; 0; 0 } }
```

Since this structure is not mine I can not override the `ToString` method, nor the `DebuggerDisplay` attribute.

Is there a simple technic for this kind of feature? I imagine it as a common requirement. Maybe something to do with VisualStudio itself as a last resort?

Precision: I am not looking for the operation (Matrix.Decompose() for the curious), just the "rendering" of variables of this type in Visual Studio (or others after all) in debug mode.

Comment: You could write a [Visualizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zayyhzts.aspx), but it's a fair bit of work for (in this case) not much return.

Comment: Yep, a bit of an overkill here. But good answer as a last resort. Thanks

Comment: This question is answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469001/can-the-debuggerdisplay-attribute-be-applied-to-types-one-doesnt-own

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can the DebuggerDisplay attribute be applied to types one doesn't own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469001/can-the-debuggerdisplay-attribute-be-applied-to-types-one-doesnt-own)