# DebuggerDisplay ignored when showing collection of items

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012

Lets say I have an object:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("Bar={bar}")]
public class Foo
{
    public String bar{get;set;}
}
```

When I have a single instance of bar the debugger correctly shows `Bar="value of bar"`
but when I have a dictionary of `Foo`s, the dictionary shows:

```
{[key, namespace.Foo]}
```

when I expand the kvp I get the expected debugger display string.

When I override `ToString()` in `Foo` and have a dictionary of `Foo`
the dictionary shows:

```
{[key, Bar="value of bar"]}
```

According to the documentation, `ToString()` is only used for debugger display if a `DebuggerDisplay` Attribute doesn't override it...

How do I get the debuggerDisplay attribute to override the debugger string in enumerated situations in addition to single instances?

Comment: You'd have to create you own type derived from `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` and attribute it with `DebuggerDisplayAttribute`

Answer (score 1):

An elegant solution to this problem is to apply the `DebuggerDisplay`
attribute to `System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>`
via `AssemblyInfo.cs` as follows:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

[assembly: DebuggerDisplay("[Key={Key}, Value={Value}]", Target = typeof(KeyValuePair<,>))]
```

([Source on StackoverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469001/can-the-debuggerdisplay-attribute-be-applied-to-types-one-doesnt-own))

Comment: This solution does not work for me; I just get [Key=0, Value={namespace.Foo}]

Comment: This does not work in Visual Studio 2022, at least with `KeyValuePair<>` it doesn't. It has no effect whatsoever.