# Modifying external DebuggerDisplay with autoexp.cs in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

[It's possible to alter the way the VS debugger displays types even for types you don't own by altering `autoexp.cs`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469001/can-the-debuggerdisplay-attribute-be-applied-to-types-one-doesnt-own).

However, in my installation this file does not exist in `My Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Visualizers/` nor in another folder. It does exist in the 2013 folder: `My Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Visualizers/autoexp.cs`

Did its location change? Has the functionality been (re)moved?

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers\Original

Comment: The question you reference has since received an answered on how to do it in Visual Studio 2015 and newer

Answer (score 1):

It is still possible to place visualizer dll's in this folder, the file just isn't there by default anymore.