# Can the DebuggerDisplay attribute be applied to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range?

Tags: .net, debugging, com, vsto, ms-office

Depending on what is asked on this question [Can the DebuggerDisplay attribute be applied to types one doesn't own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34697240/7206675), can one apply the `DebuggerDisplay` attribute to types from external assemblies?

If so, is there a way apply it specifically to a `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range`?

---

I tried the following code and it did not work:

```vb
<Assembly: DebuggerDisplay("text: {Text}", Target:=GetType(Word.Range))>
```

At a runtime Debuger displlays this string:

```
{System.__ComObject}
```

But 'System.__ComObject' is not accessible because it is 'Friend'.

Comment: The debugger probably can't use the transparent proxy used for COM objects in the same way that runtime code can. Try a `DebuggerTypeProxy` instead (even if it's a bit more work)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Can you give an example for DebuggerTypeProxy ?

Comment: [Sure](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/debugger/using-the-debuggerdisplay-attribute). (Despite the title, it covers `DebuggerTypeProxy` as well.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But 'System.__ComObject' is not accessible because it is 'Friend'.

That's true. However `System.__ComObject` inherits from public `MarshalByRefObject`. And `DebuggerDisplay` attribute will work for all derived classes if you set it for their base class. So you could set `typeof(MarshalByRefObject)` as a target for `DebuggerDisplay` attribute.

If you do this, you can't just use `{Text}` in formatter because `MarshalByRefObject` does not have such property. To overcome this, you could define the simple static helper that will check what is the type of passed object. If it's a `Range` it will call `Text` on it. Otherwise it will default to `obj.ToString()`:

```
public static class DisplayHelper
{
    public static string DisplayRange(MarshalByRefObject obj)
    {
        var range = obj as Range;
        return range?.Text ?? obj?.ToString() ?? "The value is null";
    }
}
```

Now you could set `DebuggerDisplay` attribute:

```
[assembly: DebuggerDisplay("text: {FullNamespace.Here.DisplayHelper.DisplayRange(this)}"
           , Target = typeof(MarshalByRefObject))]
```

Be sure to specify full namespace for `DisplayHelper` class (replace `FullNamespace.Goes.Here` with your actual namespace).

Here is result view in the debugger:

[image]

Comment: Can I apply it somehow to all object types in my class, let's say in one specific namespace? This one works, but can I avoid duplicating it for all types? My extension accepts object
[assembly: DebuggerDisplay("{WebApi.Models.DebuggerExtension.ToDebuggerString(this)}", Target = typeof(WebApi.Models.User))]