# Cross language DataRow index in DebuggerDisplay

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, debuggerdisplay

I am trying to customize debugged objects tooltips. To achieve this I have a library including `Assembly: DebuggerDisplay` attributes ([Can the DebuggerDisplay attribute be applied to types one doesn't own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469001)) in Visualizers folder ([How to: Install a Visualizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-install-a-visualizer?view=vs-2017)).

I would like to see a DataRow index so I have in vb.net

```vb
<Assembly: DebuggerDisplay("Idx = {Table.Rows.IndexOf(Me)}", Target:=GetType(DataRow))>
```

or in c#

```
[assembly: DebuggerDisplay(@"Idx = {Table.Rows.IndexOf(this)}", Target = typeof(DataRow))]
```

The problem is that the expression is evaluated in debug time and the object self reference (`Me` x `this`) is different in both languages. So I am getting

```
CS0103  The name 'Me' does not exist in the current context
```

in the tooltip when I am debugging c# code.

**Is there a way to get the index of DataRow with syntax common to both languages?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code of [Rows.IndexOf](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataRowCollection.cs,079bae9b61a9f3d4,references)

```
    public Int32 IndexOf(DataRow row) {
        if ((null == row) || (row.Table != this.table) || ((0 == row.RBTreeNodeId) && (row.RowState == DataRowState.Detached))) //Webdata 102857
            return -1;
        return list.IndexOf(row.RBTreeNodeId, row);
    }
```

shows that it returns the result of [list.IndexOf](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/RbTree.cs,d6bb7901fde70e75)

```
    public int IndexOf (int nodeId, K item)
    {
        int index = -1;
        // BIG ASSUMPTION: There is not satellite tree, this is INDEX_ONLY.
        if (nodeId != NIL)
        {
            if ( (Object) Key(nodeId) == (Object)item) {
                return GetIndexByNode(nodeId);
            }
            if ( (index=IndexOf(Left(nodeId), item)) != -1) {
                return index;
            }
            if ( (index=IndexOf(Right(nodeId), item)) != -1) {
                return index;
            }
        }

        return index;
    }
```

If we assume that it is valid to call `GetIndexByNode` directly and pass the `DataRow.RBTreeNodeId` value directly, then the following should work.

```
[assembly: DebuggerDisplay(@"Index = {Table.Rows.list.GetIndexByNode(RBTreeNodeId)}", Target = typeof(System.Data.DataRow))]
```